# How to get current playing song on mac by command line tools?

Tags: macos, applescript

I can only find some applescripts on Google with specific music app(like itunes, spotify, etc) to get current playing song.

But now I'm using Netease Music which not supporting to be controled by applescript, I wonder if there is any universal way to get current playing song info via mac media center?

Applescript and other command line tools both ok.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a cli tool that lets you read properties from the private `MediaRemote` framework.

https://github.com/kirtan-shah/nowplaying-cli

Since it uses private APIs, it may break with future macOS updates but is currently working on Ventura 13.1.

Here is an example that will retrieve the song name:
[image: now playing center screenshot]

[image: nowplaying-cli usage]

Comment: Amazing bro! Starred.

Comment: @Mopip77L you should mark this answer as the solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

[image: enter image description here1]

This following **AppleScript** code uses UI scripting to retrieve the currently playing media.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Control Center"
    click menu bar item "Control Center" of menu bar 1
    set currentlyPlaying to value of static text 3 of window "Control Center"
    key code 53 -- press 'esc' key
end tell

activate
display dialog currentlyPlaying with title "Currently Playing" buttons ¬
    {"OK"} default button 1 giving up after 3
```

[image: enter image description here2]